A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > Could not get unknown property 'flutterRoot' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Slava\AndroidStudioProjects\fbiblioteka\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.


**android/build.gradle**
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

**android/app/build.gradle**
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    namespace 'com.example.fbiblioteka'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.fbiblioteka"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}

pabspec.yaml
name: fbiblioteka
description: "A new Flutter project."

publish_to: 'none' 


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.3 <4.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^2.10.0


  firebase_auth: ^4.4.0

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

it`s my first question, so idk what i must write
So i did search resolve of this bug but didn`t found it
